# Cannot import data using HTML Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml, python-requests-html

So I am making a python project where I've decided to make a supermarket comparison thing. I've decided to leech the prices from an existing supermarket comparison website.

I used this website to learn:
https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/

To start I've attempted to fetch the price of apples (at Tesco) from this website:

http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price-comparison/Fruit/Tesco_Gala_Apple_Approx_160g.html

using an edited version of the docs code which is:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
page = requests.get('http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price-comparison/Fruit/Tesco_Gala_Apple_Approx_160g.html')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    price_tesco = tree.xpath('//*[@id="PriceWrp"]/div[2]/span')
    print(price_tesco)
```

I've tried the xpath code for the price but when I print the price, it returns nothing (an empty list)

So how would I fix this?

Note - I am new to HTML Scraping and have a basic knowledge of python but decided to have a bit of a challenge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't view the site in question (behind a firewall), but you should know that a lot of websites nowadays have dynamic contents using javascripts and such and can't be properly scraped using a basic library, which I'm assuming is the case here if your `xpath` is indeed correct but returning nothing.

Your best bet is to use a library that can render and scrape these type of dynamic contents, such as [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), or [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) (my preference since it's headless).

Answer (score 1):

because its a javascript rendered page use [requests_html](https://html.python-requests.org/#javascript-support) with render like:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price- 
comparison/Fruit/Tesco_Gala_Apple_Approx_160g.html')
r.html.render()
price = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="PriceWrp"]/div[2]/span')[0]
print(price.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've run the code but it throws a lot of errors at me after it downloaded some chromium thing. "pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Cannot find context with specified id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: " followed my many more errors. Have I done something wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: My IDE (Pycharm) also throws this at me: Unresolved attribute reference 'html' for class 'Response' . whenever '.html' is referenced.

Comment: python 3 or 2 ? and do "pip freeze" in your shell.

Comment: 3, I&#39;m using pycharm so i can&#39;t really use the shell at the same time as running the code I think. So would there be any alternative options eg chnaging the code around a bit to change it.

Comment: Any updates on the answer? Sorry if I'm rushing you in any way.

Comment: Are there any updates or should I just close this question?

Comment: please show my this pycharm section in settings https://imgur.com/a/yJsYnyh

Comment: Here is the one the ide gives before running: http: // prntscr.com / l6t0gy. And here is the one given when running the program: http://prntscr.com/l6t14u. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1325 maby  the version of puppeter

Comment: So should I update it or downgrade it, the thread is quite confusing an all over the place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181977/discussion-between-tic-fly-and-mtt2p).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this site is dynamic and does not let you to get full html file. You can use "selenium" library for this case, little slower but always solves your problems.